# Row-wise percentage with R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks something like this, but for the whole year

```
 date       v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  Fraction   Percent
01-02-2013  0    0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0.625
01-03-2013  0    0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0.25
01-04-2013  0    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0.125
01-05-2013  0    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0.125
01-06-2013  0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
....................................................
....................................................
```

My interest is to calculate the percentage of the Fraction column. I tried using the `prop.table` but it didn't work. 
I also tried

```
df$Percent <- df$Fraction * 100
```

it gave me the following error

```
Error in df$Fraction[i] * 100 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I have tried doing this in a loop and here is the code that i have used

```
df$Fraction <- 'NA'
df$Percent <- 'NA'
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$Fraction[i] <- round(sum(df[i, 2:9], na.rm=F)/8, 2)
  # I have used only one of the following at one time
  df$Percent[i] <- prop.table(as.array(df$Fraction[i]), margin= 2) *100
  df$Percent[i] <- df$Fraction[i] * 100
}
```

Comment: Check the class of Fraction. It would be non-numeric.  You converted the column from numeric to non-numeric by using quoted NA.  Just do `NA` instead of character NA.

Comment: `df$Fraction <- as.numeric(df$Fraction) * 100`

Comment: the class of `fraction` is `character`

Comment: Just do `df$Fraction <- NA` as your first line of code. along with `df$Percent <- NA`.  BTW, you don't need any loop here.  Probably, `prop.table(round(rowSums(df[2:9], na.rm=TRUE)/8,2), margin=2)*100`

Comment: thanks @akrun it works

Comment: thanks @Mateusz1981 it works. i was trying to multiply a character with a numeric

Comment: yeah that will also work. Thanks @akrun  :)

Comment: Your code gives me error.

Comment: But its working for me, once i unquoted the `NA` . @akrun

Comment: now the code i am using looks something like this

`df$Fraction <- NA`
`df$Percent <- NA`
`for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {`
  `df$Fraction[i] <- round(sum(df[i, 2:9], na.rm=F)/8, 2)`
`}`

`df$Percent <- df$Fraction * 100`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a `for` loop, we can do this with `rowSums`

```
df$Fraction <- rowSums(df[2:9], na.rm=TRUE)/8
df$Percent <- 100*df$Fraction
```

Or as @ColonelBeauvel mentioned, `rowMeans` will be more compact and appropriate.

```
df$Fraction <- rowMeans(df[2:9], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: @ShretaGhimire Sorry, didn't test it earlier.

Comment: why not directly `rowMeans`?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel  You could post that as an answer.  I was just trying to follow the similar logic as in the OP's post.

Comment: no worries, you can add it additionally to enrich your answer. Will avoid multiple-redundant answers on a simple question ;)

Answer (score 1):

The following code works perfectly for me

```
df$Fraction <- NA
df$Percent <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$Fraction[i] <- round(sum(df[i, 2:9], na.rm=F)/8, 2)
}

df$Percent <- df$Fraction * 100


# Alternative
df$Frac <- round(rowSums(df[2:9], na.rm=T)/8, 2)
df$Percent <- 100*df$Frac
```

I found two solution for the question i posted.

**1.** I can unquote the `NA` that I have assigned, so the whole column becomes `logical` and hence i can calculate the percentage(or multiply the column with 100).

**2.** I can use `as.numeric` if i have quotes the `'NA'`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the `Fraction` variable is not numeric.
Try this

`df$Fraction <- as.numeric(df$Fraction) * 100`

Comment: The problem was due to a typo.

Comment: The problem was due to the `class` of the column @Pascal

Comment: Right.  And you can solve that by changing to `df$Fraction <- NA_real_` at the first line of your code.

Comment: Yes, because you used `'NA'` instead of `NA`.

Comment: Yes. i tried that too. I got so many problems in my code and solutions to them :). thanks @Pascal